# React Native datetimepicker re-renders back to default value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement this [solution found here](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/182) but I am running into the following error. `Error: rendered more hooks than during the previous render`

Here is my code. What am I missing? Am I implementing the solution correctly?

```
export default function Foo(){
const [showCalendar, setShowCalendar] = useState(false);

   function fooA(newDate){
      onChange(newDate)// function that updates date, works on ios. I do not think its the issue.
    setShowCalendar(false)

   }

   function fooB(){
     {React.useMemo(() => {
        return (
          <RNDateTimePicker 
            onChange={fooA(newDate)} 
            value={date} 
            display='spinner' 
            {...rest} 
          />
        )
      }, [showCalendar])}
   }

   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowCalendar(true)}>
        fooB()
      </TouchableOpacity>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, any hooks that you use, such as `useState` or `useMemo`, must be invoked *every time* your component function is invoked.  If a hook is conditionally called, or if there's any other scenario where the hook doesn't always get called, you get the error that you're seeing.  To fix this, move your call to `useMemo` out of `fooB`:

```js
const fooB = React.useMemo(() => {
        return (
          <RNDateTimePicker 
            onChange={fooA(newDate)} 
            value={date} 
            display='spinner' 
            {...rest} 
          />
        )
      }, [showCalendar]);

   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowCalendar(true)}>
        {fooB}
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Now `useMemo` will be invoked consistently.